# Testing Smart Contract with multiple clients

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, ropsten

After deploying a smart contract on Ropsten Testnet using Truffle framework, we can use truffle tests to do unit testing (create a client to interact with the deployed contract). My question is, how can we set up multiple clients to interact with the deployed contract parallelly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{from: player)`.

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require( ...

var myContract;
var player1; // <== the actors
var player2;

contract("MyContract", accounts => { // <== pass the accounts object in

  beforeEach( async () => { // <== beforeEach is one way to get started. 
    [ player1, player2 ] = accounts; // <== set up the players
    myContract = await MyContract.deployed();
  }

  it("should use player2", async {} => { 
    var txn;     
    txn = await myContract.doSomething({from: player2}); // <== use it
    // carry on
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.